# shopping cart rules for multiple countries?

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules

OK, starting to panic, as I have a deadline today and cannot workout the logic for shopping cart rules. Can someone help?

I need to have
- country A and B, with subtotal of 150 or greater - gets free shipping
- country C, with subtotal of 250 or greater - gets free shipping

I can't work out how to have this nested logic working. Any tips pls!?

Fixed it with this:

```
If ANY  of these conditions are TRUE :
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE : 
Subtotal  equals or greater than  100  
If ANY  of these conditions are TRUE : 
Shipping Country  is  Austria  
Shipping Country  is  Germany  


If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE : 
Subtotal  equals or greater than  200  
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE : 
Shipping Country  is  Switzerland
```

Comment: Consider adding the solution as the answer, it helps other people to find it.

Comment: I am also facing this issue, when shipping country used in condition of rule, rule says invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reposting solution that was added to the question:

```
If ANY  of these conditions are TRUE :
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE : 
Subtotal  equals or greater than  100  
If ANY  of these conditions are TRUE : 
Shipping Country  is  Austria  
Shipping Country  is  Germany  


If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE : 
Subtotal  equals or greater than  200  
If ALL  of these conditions are TRUE : 
Shipping Country  is  Switzerland
```

Comment: Egg, can you mark this as the solution so others can find it? ;)

Comment: yep, will do! Just had to wait 2 days to be able to do so  (though I see now its yours haha very confusing) :)